# how to groupby dataframe and use columns as values

Tags: python, pandas

Working with python pandas.

my datatable is like this:

```
userid    roomid    true
 a         A         1   
 a         B         1
 b         C         0
 b         D         1
```

and what i want is like:

```
userid    roomid1   roomid2   true1  true2
 a         A         B        1      1   
 b         C         D        0      1
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and then reshape by  [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last flatten `MultiIndex` by `map` with `join`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['userid', df.groupby(['userid']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)])
        .unstack())
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(''.join)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  userid roomid1 roomid2  true1  true2
0      a       A       B      1      1
1      b       C       D      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to group by the column you want group. It seems you want to group `userid` After that I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. You need to explain what the end result you need, not how you plan to get there. check the [XY promblem](http://xyproblem.info/) and then ask the question correctly

`df.groupby('userid')`